# Array.prototype function not working for document.forms[0].elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, prototype

I have built a prototype function for Arrays and it doesn't allow me to use it with an array from document.forms[0].elements. Here is a simplified script that shows this problem

```
<html>
<body>

<form id="frm1" action="form_action.asp">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="Donald" /><br />
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Duck" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form> 


<p>Return the value of each element in the form:</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
Array.prototype.returnFirst = function(){
   return this[0];
}
alert([1,2,3].returnFirst()); //Why does this work?
alert(document.forms[0].elements.returnFirst().id); //but this one doesn't?
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You will see with this that the returnFirst() prototype function works for my [1,2,3] array but not for my array of elements? Why is this, it is still an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a real array, so it doesn't inherit `Array.prototype`.

It's actually an `HTMLCollection`, as you can discover by calling `toString()` on it.

If you want to, you can modify `HTMLCollection.prototype`, but [modifying DOM prototypes is discouraged](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

**EDIT**:

You can turn it into a real array by calling

```
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.forms[0].elements);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. That clears it up. I justt I can just turn it into an Array as follows (this appears to work, but I am unsure if it is advisable) var elems = document.forms[0].elements;
//alert(elems.returnFirst().name);
var newArr = new Array();
var i = elems.length;
while(i--){
newArr.push(elems[i]);
}
newArr.reverse();
alert(newArr.returnFirst().name);